# after using dotfuscator when browse it can't fined pages

Tags: asp.net, dotfuscator

I used dotfuscator to encrypet my dlls and on post build event I wrote command to get the encrypted dlls instad of old ones and finally i published my website.
but when i browse it it give me error it can't fine login page?
any help

Answer (score 0):

Don't obfuscate public classes and public method names. If they are changed (obfuscated) the other objects referencing them cannot find them and you will get this error.

Comment: I've not used dotfuscator extensively but there are settings which allow you to obfuscate the control flow only and not rename public classes and methods.